# Link tag outside of div causes empty spaces

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, sass

I have a problem with my appended `div`'s inside a link. I want them to be all connected without empty space at the bottom. I figured out that this is an `<a>` tag issue.

Here is the link to my codepen and an image presenting the issue:

http://codepen.io/Felnyr/pen/WRGRyQ

**Image from Inspector:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues I see with your pen.

1. In the JS, you're missing a double quote after `href=\"#\` on line 9.
2. To fix the bottom margin issue, you could just change the line-height to 0 for the channel boxes parent.

Like this:

```
.channelBoxes
  line-height: 0
```

This fixes issues at all responsive breakpoints.

---

To keep the text formatted correctly. You can use a negative bottom margin but this may not be complete cross-browser compatible (especially some Android browsers seem to have trouble).  You could add `margin-bottom: -10px` to your .Box css.

Comment: This soulution fixes the problem with divs but now my spans are broken when u hover over divs.

Comment: See if the 2nd solution is better for your text

Comment: still no good. This empty space happened when i changed the appenging code in JS. Before there was <div><a><img><span> but i thrown away the img and instead applied css style `background-image` to cover the div. Still don't know how to fix this problem

Comment: edited solution. the above works for me with your current code

Comment: Ok i found a solution! I applied `vertical-align: top` to my .Box class and now everything works like charm

Comment: this margin-bottom solves problem partially. Divs are connected but text is off the edge. Still thank you for commitment!